# What are the products in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

I came across this question
[image]

I thought that the answer should be option (a)but the answer is given option (d)
I thought that other products might be a result of the following mechanism[image]

But this cannot be the case as a positive charge still remains on the carbon atom. Can you please help me figure out where I am going wrong?
UPDATE:
Or is this a possible mechanism[image]
But I am still unclear about how the double bond will reappear between 3 position and the carbon that carried Chlorine

Comment: FWIW, in my browser both links say "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors". That might just be me and my somewhat odd browser, but it's good if you can insert images into your question rather than links. Anyway, you got an answer, so I guess someone can see them ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arene_substitution_pattern

Comment: @airhuff I am rather new to this site and so I don't know how to add an image in my question. I admit adding links of images is a cumbersome process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- List item

All the reactions eliminate chloride (a) by the obvious direct attack, the other products b and c arise from methoxide attack on the 3 and 5 positions of the furan and chloride loss via an exomethylene intermediate. The system is somewhat similar to a polyallyl choride where attack can be direct or at the 3 or 5 position.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what an exomethylene intermediate is.

Comment: Double band from carbon at 2 position (next to oxygen) to carbon that carried chlorine

Comment: But how will chlorine leave? Will you please add the mechanism of its loss in your answer

Comment: I have no access to a drawing package. Chlorine leaves as Cl- just as in the direct attack.  Consider product c to be result of Michael attack at the 3 position and move the bonds around to kick out Cl-

Comment: from what i understood,I've added a mechanism in my question, I am very sure that it's not correct. will you please go through it once ?

Comment: @DaenysTargaryen  The first two steps are probably more concerted than that, also, $\ce{CH_3O^-}$ will act as base, formally yielding NaCl.

Comment: The mechanism you added is fundamentally correct. As TAR86 says methoxide will remove the proton leading to re-aromatisation. The same mechanism applies to attack at the 5 position.

Comment: Ok,but when the double bond between carbon at position 2 and the CH2 break,there will be a positive charge left on it. How do I get a -CH3 group there

Comment: The exo carbon will pick up a proton from the MeOH. You could visualise it as a 1,3 proton shift